# unable to create new remote session with remotewebdriver and gecko driver SessionNotCreatedException with Firefox

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-grid, geckodriver, gecko

I am having issues with connecting selenium webdriver with firefox using GeckoDriver.

**My Firefox version is - Mozilla Firefox 52.8.1**

**pom.xml**

```
 <properties>
    <selenium.version>3.3.0</selenium.version>
</properties>
```

```
    <!-- Selenium -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-firefox-driver</artifactId>
        <version>${selenium.version}</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-support</artifactId>
    <version>${selenium.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-java</artifactId>
        <version>${selenium.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-remote-driver</artifactId>
        <version>${selenium.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.seleniumhq.selenium</groupId>
        <artifactId>selenium-api</artifactId>
        <version>${selenium.version}</version>
    </dependency>
```

**Command to start hub -**

```
 /data1/jdk-8u131-linux-x64/jdk1.8.0_131/bin/java -jar $BUILD_REPOSITORY/org/seleniumhq/seleniuselenium-server-standalone/3.141.5/selenium-server-standalone-3.141.5.jar -role hub -port 4444
```

**Command to start Node -**

```
 /usr/java64/jre1.8.0_181-amd64/bin/java -Dwebdriver.gecko.driver=/usr/g/ctuser/geckodriver -jar selenium-server-standalone-3.141.5.jar -role node -huhttp://3.57.51.87:4444/grid/register -host 3.231.15.68
```

**GeckoDriver - geckodriver-v0.15.0-linux64.tar.gz**

**Test Code -**

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "/export/data1/selenium/geckodriver");
    DesiredCapabilities firefox = DesiredCapabilities.firefox();
    firefox.setBrowserName("firefox");
    firefox.setPlatform(Platform.UNIX);
    RemoteWebDriver remoteDriver = new RemoteWebDriver(firefox);
    remoteDriver.get("http://localhost:7005/"); 
    System.out.println(remoteDriver.getTitle());
    remoteDriver.quit();
}
```

**Getting Exception -**

> Exception in thread "main"
>   org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create new
>   remote session. desired capabilities = Capabilities {browserName:
>   firefox, marionette: true, platform: UNIX, version: } Build info:
>   version: '3.141.5', revision: 'd54ebd709a', time:
>   '2018-11-06T11:58:47' System info: host: 'liblab8.site', ip:
>   '3.231.15.68', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version:
>   '3.0.101-0.47.106.35.1.15690.0.PTF-default', java.version: '1.8.0_181'
>   Driver info: driver.version: unknown Command duration or timeout: 0
>   milliseconds  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:216)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:168)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:363)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:113)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:141)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:604)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:244)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:131)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:158)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:148)
>     at com.ge.test.Test1.main(Test1.java:16) Caused by:
>   org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Unable to create new
>   remote session. desired capabilities = Capabilities {browserName:
>   firefox, marionette: true, platform: UNIX, version: } Build info:
>   version: '3.141.5', revision: 'd54ebd709a', time:
>   '2018-11-06T11:58:47' System info: host: 'liblab8.site', ip:
>   '3.231.15.68', os.name: 'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version:
>   '3.0.101-0.47.106.35.1.15690.0.PTF-default', java.version: '1.8.0_181'
>   Driver info: driver.version: unknown Build info: version: '3.3.0',
>   revision: 'b526bd5b41', time: '2017-03-07 19:26:04 +0000' System info:
>   host: 'ctwdof067.am.health.ge.com', ip: '3.57.51.87', os.name:
>   'Linux', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '3.0.101-0.40-default',
>   java.version: '1.8.0_131' Driver info: driver.version: unknown    at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake.createSession(ProtocolHandshake.java:87)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.grid.session.remote.RemoteSession$Factory.performHandshake(RemoteSession.java:147)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.grid.session.remote.ServicedSession$Factory.apply(ServicedSession.java:161)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.ActiveSessionFactory.lambda$apply$12(ActiveSessionFactory.java:180)
>     at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$11$1.accept(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.util.Spliterators$ArraySpliterator.tryAdvance(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(Unknown Source)
>     at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source)
>     at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source)
>     at java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
>     at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(Unknown Source)  at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.ActiveSessionFactory.apply(ActiveSessionFactory.java:183)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.NewSessionPipeline.lambda$null$2(NewSessionPipeline.java:66)
>     at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.util.Collections$2.tryAdvance(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(Unknown Source)
>     at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source)
>     at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source)
>     at java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
>     at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(Unknown Source)  at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.NewSessionPipeline.lambda$createNewSession$3(NewSessionPipeline.java:69)
>     at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.util.stream.DistinctOps$1$2.accept(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$3$1.accept(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.util.stream.Streams$StreamBuilderImpl.tryAdvance(Unknown Source)
>     at java.util.stream.Streams$ConcatSpliterator.tryAdvance(Unknown
>   Source)   at
>   java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEachWithCancel(Unknown Source)
>     at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyIntoWithCancel(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(Unknown Source)
>     at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(Unknown Source)
>     at java.util.stream.FindOps$FindOp.evaluateSequential(Unknown Source)
>     at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(Unknown Source)   at
>   java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.findFirst(Unknown Source)  at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.NewSessionPipeline.createNewSession(NewSessionPipeline.java:72)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.commandhandler.BeginSession.execute(BeginSession.java:65)
>     at
>   org.openqa.selenium.remote.server.WebDriverServlet.lambda$handle$0(WebDriverServlet.java:235)
>     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown
>   Source)   at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)  at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)    at
>   java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

**Hub Console -**

> 01:47:49.231 INFO [RequestHandler.process] - Got a request to create a
>   new session: Capabilities {browserName: firefox, marionette: true,
>   platform: UNIX, version: } 01:47:49.232 INFO [TestSlot.getNewSession]
>   - Trying to create a new session on test slot {server:CONFIG_UUID=e18d691a-1d36-4b44-8526-777d4443d078,
>   seleniumProtocol=WebDriver, marionette=true, browserName=firefox,
>   maxInstances=5, platformName=LINUX, platform=LINUX}

**Node Console -**

> 01:43:34.137 INFO [ActiveSessionFactory.apply] - Capabilities are: {
>   "browserName": "firefox",   "marionette": true,   "platform": "UNIX", 
>   "version": "" } 01:43:34.137 INFO
>   [ActiveSessionFactory.lambda$apply$11] - Matched factory
>   org.openqa.selenium.grid.session.remote.ServicedSession$Factory
>   (provider: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.GeckoDriverService)
>   1542008614143 geckodriver INFO    Listening on 127.0.0.1:43589
>   1542008614199 mozprofile::profile INFO    Using profile path
>   /tmp/rust_mozprofile.bGje3sR6MQxe
>   1542008614199 geckodriver::marionette INFO    Starting browser
>   /usr/bin/firefox with args []
>   1542008614201 geckodriver::marionette INFO    Connecting to Marionette on
>   localhost:56293 1542008615126 Marionette  INFO    Listening on port 56293
>   NPP_GetValue() NPP_GetValue() NPP_GetValue() NPP_GetValue()

I don't understand what is going on here. Please help